信ずべき: What does it mean exactly?
彼らの笑みを受けたことがある者ならば、彼らを失うなどできないはずだ。
そんな信ずべき存在は、自分にもいる。
The characters are in mortal dangers. So one character debates no one cares if they die. The narrator however thinks this.
In the first line he explains that "If there are people who will accept their smiles,there are people who can't lose them"
What exactly is a  "信ずべき存在"? I take he's saying "Such an existence exists inside of me as well"?

I won't go into a translation of this sentence as a whole since it's two ambiguous to provide a full translation, but firstly “信ずべき” is simply an older form of “信じるべき”. This stems from that the regular ru-verb “信じる” came from “信ずる” which is simply “信” + “する” but undergoing sequential voicing, you may or may not know that “べき” typically but  not always attaches to “する” as simply “すべき”, a remnant from older Japanese again where the conclusive form of “する" was simply “す”. Also “べき” can on it's own serve as the attributive form and modify a noun directly as it does here, as well as on it's own serve as a nominalized phrase without needing “〜の” as it very much functions as a classical Japanese adjective.
Furthermore, the sentence above does not mean “if there are people”, “〜ならば” is a conditional form of “〜だ” here, not of “いる”. It says “if <something else> are people have once accepted their smile.” but I don't know what that something else is. Also note that “〜たことがある” expresses that something happened at least once in the past that the subject has some kind of relevant experience with. As in “日本に行ったことがある” means “I went to Japan before.” as in the speaker visited Japan at least once and can thus speak from experience about Japan in some way. The second part also means “then it should be the case that <something> is unable to lose them or anything similar” as in “はずだ” expresses high confidence in something as in “... is bound to be true” or “it should be the case that ...” and “失うなどする”.
The “信ずべき存在” part is highly ambiguous, it can mean “an existence that is to be believed” or “an existence that should believe” and I also don't know whether “そんな” modifies “存在” here or whether it's omission for “そんなのを”.
